# Using ASP.NET MVC Customed AuthorizeAttribute in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have Authorization Attribute like this

```
public class CustomAuthAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
            ...

        }
}
```

I want to use this attribute in new site that uses ASP.NET Core MVC Controller/Action.
I have tried to configure in Startup.cs like this

```
 services.AddMvc(options =>
 {
      options.Filters.Add((new CustomAuthAttribute());
 });
```

But it can not resolve the type IFilterMetadata. Anyone can help me? Thank you

Comment: This may help: https://offering.solutions/blog/articles/2017/02/07/difference-between-addmvc-addmvcore/
or 
https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/asp-net-core-anatomy-part-2-addmvc

Comment: I think they are not the solutions that I am finding

Comment: `IFilterMetadata` resides in namespace `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters`, read here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.ifiltermetadata?view=aspnetcore-2.0

Comment: @GauravSinghJantwal How can I treat AuthorizeAttribute as IFilterMetadata

Comment: any solutions resolve?